# Remover caracteres de listas python

Tags: python, xml, lista, txt

Olá eu tenho um código que le dois arquivos um `txt` e um `XML` e depois verifica uma string dentro de uma lista

O XML:

```
<nfeProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="4.00">
<NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
<infNFe Id="NFe35200861974911000104550010000742491174625832" versao="4.00">
<ide>
...
</ide>
<emit>
...
</emit>
<dest>
...
</dest>
<det nItem="1">
<prod>
<cProd>20517-0</cProd>
<cEAN>7897748715180</cEAN>
<xProd>SAFEBLOCK FUSE BLOQUEADOR AUTOMOTIVO (COM FUSIVEL DE EMERGENCIA / SIRENE OPCIONAL)</xProd>
<NCM>85123000</NCM>
<CEST>0110000</CEST>
<CFOP>5401</CFOP>
<uCom>PC</uCom>
<qCom>20.0000</qCom>
</prod>
```

O TXT:

```
0|7897748715180|||||20
```

O meu código:

```
def tratar_linha(linha):
    dados = linha.strip('\n').split('|||||')
    if len(dados) > 0:
        return dados
    return None
lista = []
#função do EAN
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def search (lista, valor):
    return [(lista.index(x), x.index(valor)) for x in lista if valor in x]
#função do EAN
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#text = input("Coloque o diretorio do fisico: ").strip('"')
with open(r"C:\Users\Expedição\Downloads\74249.txt","r", encoding="utf8") as arquivo:
    for linha in arquivo:
        dado = tratar_linha(linha)
        if dado is not None:
            lista.append(dado)
#localiza arquivo,lista todos os itens
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#XML = input("Coloque o diretorio do XML: ").strip('"')
tree = ET.parse(r"C:\Users\Expedição\Downloads\74249.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
    Contagem = 1
    ns = {'nfe': 'http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe'}
    for det in root.findall('.//nfe:det', ns):
        nItem = det.attrib['nItem']
        quantidade = det.find('.//nfe:qCom', ns).text.strip('000').strip('.')
        EAN = det.find('.//nfe:cEAN', ns).text
        if EAN is not None:
            FEAN =  "0|" + EAN
    #importa XML, obtem os campos EAN,quatidade    
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            if search(lista, FEAN):
                print(f"{Contagem} - EAN encontrado: {EAN}")
                lista.remove(FEAN)
            else:
                print(f"{Contagem} - EAN INVALIDO: {EAN}")
```

Eu tentei usar o `lista.remove(FEAN)` mas esta dando esse erro e não sei como concertar.

```
File "c:/Users/Expedição/Videos/python/Consulta.py", line 49, in <module>
    lista.remove(FEAN)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta ver como está sua lista:

```
lista = []
with open(r"texto.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as arquivo:
    for linha in arquivo:
        dado = tratar_linha(linha)
        if dado is not None:
            lista.append(dado)

print('lista=', lista)
```

Resultado:

```
lista= [['0|7897748715180', '20']]
```

Ou seja, a lista possui um elemento, que é **outra** lista (e esta contém 2 elementos: a string `'0|7897748715180'` e a string `'20'`). Isso acontece porque `split` retorna uma lista, que você inseriu na `lista`. E ela só tem 2 elementos porque você fez o `split` por `'|||||'` (ou seja, ele usou `'|||||'` - uma sequência de 5 caracteres `|` - como o separador).

---

Enfim, se quer procurar pelo código que está no txt, coloque-o diretamente na lista. Faça o `split` pelo `|` e só inclua os elementos não-vazios :

```
def tratar_linha(linha):
    dados = linha.strip('\n').split('|')
    if len(dados) > 0:
        return dados
    return None

lista = []
with open(r"texto.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as arquivo:
    for linha in arquivo:
        dado = tratar_linha(linha)
        if dado is not None:
            lista.extend([x for x in dado if x]) # exclui as strings vazias
```

Assim a lista terá o `'0'`, `'7897748715180'` e `'20'` como elementos separados.

---

Ou pegue somente o segundo campo da linha, que parece ser o que você quer:

```
def tratar_linha(linha):
    dados = linha.strip('\n').split('|')
    if len(dados) >= 2:
        return dados[1] # retorna o segundo campo (7897748715180)
    return None

lista = []
with open(r"texto.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as arquivo:
    for linha in arquivo:
        dado = tratar_linha(linha)
        if dado is not None:
            lista.append(dado) # insere o campo (7897748715180)
```

Assim eu só retorno um campo (o 7897748715180).

---

Tendo a lista só com as informações que me interessam, a busca fica fácil, não precisando concatenar o zero na frente e nem usando uma função extra com `index` nem nada disso:

```
for det in root.findall('.//nfe:det', ns):
    nItem = det.attrib['nItem']
    quantidade = det.find('.//nfe:qCom', ns).text.strip('000').strip('.')
    EAN = det.find('.//nfe:cEAN', ns).text
    if EAN is not None:
        if EAN in lista: # se está na lista
            print(f"{Contagem} - EAN encontrado: {EAN}")
            lista.remove(EAN)
        else:
            print(f"{Contagem} - EAN INVALIDO: {EAN}")
```

Veja que para verificar se um elemento está na lista, basta usar o operador `in`.

Comment: sua proposta é bem valida mas no meu caso em especifico eu preciso que a `lista` tenha os int tbm (`20`)